# Verifying correctness of kwpower output to calculate the statistical power of Kruskal-Wallis test

Tags: statistical-power, kruskal-wallis-test

```
kruskal.test(IRAmax.P ~ group, data = my_data)

Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test

data:  IRAmax.P by group
Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 20.745, df = 3, p-value = 0.0001189


  +------------------------+
  | group | Obs | Rank Sum |
  |-------+-----+----------|
  |     1 |   3 |   148.00 |
  |     2 |  36 |  1133.00 |
  |     3 |  11 |   176.00 |
  |     4 |   4 |    28.00 |
  +------------------------+

kwpower(c(3,36,11,4),c(148/3,1133/36,176/11,28/4),"normal")

$power
[1] 0.9997784
    
$ncp
[1] 36.8303
        
$cv
[1] 7.814728

$probs
     [,1]        [,2]          [,3]          [,4]
[1,]  0.5 7.24029e-37 3.894144e-123 3.534009e-197
[2,]  1.0 5.00000e-01  3.689051e-28  2.176179e-67
[3,]  1.0 1.00000e+00  5.000000e-01  9.830802e-11
[4,]  1.0 1.00000e+00  1.000000e+00  5.000000e-01

[[5]]
      [,1]
[1,] -25.5
[2,]  -6.0
[3,]  17.5
[4,]  25.0

about the help
kwpower(
  nreps,
  shifts,
  distname = c("normal", "logistic"),
  level = 0.05,
  mc = 0,
  taylor = FALSE
)
```

I am not quite sure the meaning of shifts? is it the mean rank as calculated by dividing the sum of ranks.

Comment: can you explain a bit more?

Comment: thank you for your quick response. i am trying to make it clear. i am not familiar with this website

Comment: see here https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour for a quick overview.

Comment: the shifts here i just used c(sum of ranks/sample size), is this right?

Answer (score 2):

Power calculations require that we simulate the distribution under a *known* functional form. The documentation for kwpower shows that you have only two supported options so far - normal and logistic (the latter of which so closely resembling the former, they may as well only support normal). Not stated but the additional assumption of homoscedasticity means that (in the normal case), what is called "shifts" is basically a standardized distance or Z-score. So to your specific question: no, you do not supply the mean rank(s) as the argument to shifts.

Why then is there a different terminology? At the end of the day, robust statistics (such as KW) demands generalized terminology for analogues ideas to parametric modeling. So instead of "means" we have "locations" and instead of "standard deviations" we have "spreads", consequently instead of mean differences we have "shifts". The documentation doesn't help us much either. https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/MultNonParam/versions/1.3.6/topics/kwpower

> shifts The offsets for the various populations, under the alternative hypothesis.

We can definitively say that whatever is meant by "offset" is only more confusing, mainly that it conflicts with actual well defined statistical notation (a regression model variable with a fixed, non-varying coefficient). Furthermore, a shift, therefore seems to be a shift from 0, but in a multisample test our null is of homogeneity (they all equal the same thing) not equality to 0.

The main point here is that you've already fit your analysis and there's no point whatsoever in running a power calculation on the data. It's absolutely trivial. In some scientific journals, there's a debate about whether post-hoc power needs to be calculated. But in general, methodologists see this as totally redundant. You could take $1-p$ and call that your post-hoc power.

You can therefore spare yourself the headache of working through this in too much detail. Otherwise, since you've already grasped fitting the test, you're not far from just simulating the results in R and skipping `kwpower` altogether.

Comment: I can see some point to the logistic since you'd expect the power for a K-W under shift alternatives to be relatively good at the logistic (relative to say ANOVA).

Comment: many thanks. My data are normally distributed without equal variance. I tried both simulation in two groups and kwpower, the results are very similar. i yet don't know how to perform simulation in four groups. so i have to use kwpower now. many thanks.